# Thymeleaf iterating through list of objects shows blank

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, jsp, thymeleaf

I am trying to iterate through objects passed through ModelMap using Spring MVC. However, the text shows up blank when tested on browser. For example :

test.jsp :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Hello ${test}  

<tr th:each="user,iterStat : ${testList}">
    <td th:text="${user.id}" />
    <td th:text="${user.name}" />
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code :

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("test", "Bob");
    List<ChatUser> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(new ChatUser("asdf"));
    users.add(new ChatUser("ewfasdf"));
    model.addAttribute("testList", users);
    return "test";
}
```

When loading up /test after deploying my webapp I would see Hello Bob, but nothing else. Checking the source of the webpage I see this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Hello Bob

<tr th:each="user,iterStat : [com.mkyong.ChatUser@7a5dd809, com.mkyong.ChatUser@61f4628]">
    <td th:text=""/>
    <td th:text=""/>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

As seen in the th:each line, the objects are obviously being passed through properly. But the th:text is showing up just blank.

My ChatUser entity :

```
@Entity
public class ChatUser {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;

    public ChatUser() {}

    public ChatUser(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Your template name is `.jsp`, but you seem to be using Thymeleaf (which is my recommendation). Perhaps you meant to name it `.html`?

Comment: @chrylis Ah, yes. How incredibly stupid of me. File should be named .html. Decided to port over to Thymeleaf from JSP but didn't rename file.